# What is the purpose of rvalue reference to an array in C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, rvalue-reference

Arrays can not be returned by value from function (only by reference/constant reference) both in C++03 and C++11 (because we can not assign one array to another directly):

```
const size_t N = 10;
using Element = int;
using Array = Element[N];

Array array;

// does not compile
// Array GetArray()
// {
//     return array;
// }

Array& GetArrayRef()
{
    return array;
}
```

In C++ there was introduced a new reference type - rvalue reference. It can be used with arrays, too:

```
void TakeArray(Array&& value)
{
}

// ...

TakeArray(std::forward<Array>(array));
TakeArray(std::forward<Array>(GetArrayRef()));
```

What is the purpose of such reference (rvalue reference to an array)? Can it be used in any real code or is it only a defect of C++11 standard?

Comment: Your first assumption is not fully correct. With c++11 you can define a std::array<Element,N>, which can be returned by value.

Comment: @MatthiasB `std::array` is not an array, it is `std` container.

Comment: @Constructor I'd argue that `int array[]` is not an array, but a relic of C Compatibility.  `std::array` is more a true array (violates Principle of Least Surprise far less)

Comment: There are actual possible uses for this (see @Yakk).  But still, some things that aren't useful are still legal, like an rvalue reference member of a class.  It's not a defect, just nobody saw any reason to bother making it illegal.

Comment: @SamCristall Possibly you are right. :-) But but still they are in the standard, so...

Comment: @aschepler Yes, 'defect' is too loud word for such situation, I agree with you. But the existence of such things is strange, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know. With the assumtion that an array is not too much more than a nice way of using pointers, you are basically writing `TakeArray((int*)&& value)`.

Comment: It isn't different from any other move operation. You wouldn't expect a pointer to an object to be moving the actual object, so why should the code differ with arrays.

Comment: @MatthiasB Because you can not return arrays from functions as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I still don't get the connection, sorry. It just moves what you insert. So if you insert a pointer, it moves it. If you insert the array reference (a pointer), it moves it. I mean, I get that it may not does what someone might expect, but only if they expect the array to be physically moved in the first place.

Comment: @MatthiasB I thought that if array can not be returned from function there is no way to obtain it as a rvalue (so rvalue reference is not needed), but Matthieu M. in his answer gives an example of how such unnamed objects can be obtained and Yakk in his answer gives a good code which illustrates the possibility of use of rvalue references to an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An rvalue reference is a promise by either the programmer or compiler that the data being referred to is about to be disposed of<sup>1</sup>, and that the reader changing it in reasonable ways is acceptable if it makes reading faster (among other things).

If you are copying from an array of `vector` with the above promise, you can clearly `move` the contained `vector`s for a possibly massive performance boost.

So no, this is not a defect.

```
std::vector<int> data[1000];
void populate_data() {
  for( auto& v : data )
    v.resize(1000);
}
template<std::size_t N>
std::vector< std::vector<int> > get_data( std::vector<int>(&&arr)[N] ) {
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > retval;
  retval.reserve(N);
  for( auto& v : arr )
    retval.emplace_back( std::move(v) );
  return retval;
}
template<std::size_t N>
std::vector< std::vector<int> > get_data( std::vector<int>(const&arr)[N] ) {
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > retval;
  retval.reserve(N);
  for( auto const& v : arr )
    retval.emplace_back( v );
  return retval;
}
int main() {
  populate_data();
  auto d = get_data(data); // copies the sub-vectors
  auto d2 = get_data( std::move(data) ); // moves the sub-vectors
}
```

in this case, things are a bit contrived, but in general the source of the data could be `move`d from or not.  The rvalue override does a move of the sub-data if the entire container is `move`d from (an rvalue reference), and otherwise does a copy.

With a bit more work, we could write the above so that it all happens in one method.  So if we have an rvalue container (aka owning range), and the container itself isn't suitable for being moved from directly, we `move` the contents.  But that is just advanced metaprogramming, and not essential to the answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> The compiler does this in restricted situations involving the object being "impossible" to reference after the use, either because it is an anonymous temporary or because it is being used in certain circumstances in return values of functions.  (It is not actually impossible, and in theory this C++11 feature could break pre-C++11 code, but it is pretty close).  Programmers do this by an rvalue cast.  What exactly it means that it will be "disposed of immediately" depends on context, but the general rule is that the consumer of the rvalue reference can put the object into any "valid" state that can still be destroyed and interacted with.  The existence of rvalue-based `swap` means that putting it into a state that can **only** be destroyed is not safe.

Comment: Could you give an example of code which which would have illustrated your words?

Comment: Thank you very much! It's interesting, I'll think about how to implement this in one function.

Comment: @Constructor it gets messy.  Your function signature becomes `template<typename C>void get_data( C&& c )`.  You'll want helper functions that answer things like "is this an owning container", "get me the size of this view if there is an efficient way, otherwise 0", and "`move_if<bool>`" (or `make_move_iterator_if<bool>`) then create a `constexpr bool move_from = std::is_rvalue_ref< C&& >::value` to control moving or not.  Things get easier post-concepts as well.

Comment: Yes, I also thought it can be implemented somehow like that.

Comment: Shouldn't `auto& v` be `auto&& v`  in the foreach loop of the rvalue overload or am I misunderstanding how rvalues work?

Comment: @pro-g yes you do misunderstand. `arr` is an rvalue reference, but as an expression is an lvalue.  It is tricky, but named stuff are lvalues in almost every context (a few exceptions have been added).

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely correct that you can't have array temporaries. You can

```
void f(const std::string(&&x)[2]) {
   std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}

void f(const std::string(&x)[2]) {
   std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
using id = T;

int main() {
  f(id<std::string[]>{"Hello", "Folks"});
  f(id<std::string const[]>{"Hello", "Folks"});

  std::string array[] = { "Hello", "Folks" };
  std::string const arrayConst[] = { "Hello", "Folks" };
  f(array);
  f(arrayConst);
}
```

Starting with C++14, [you are also allowed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/681f417ebf62285b) to pass a braced init list directly to the rvalue overload

```
f({ "Hello", "Folks" });
```

Comment: Excellent! But this can be made without using of alias template: `f((std::string[]){"Hello", "Folks"});`. And what do you want to show in second pair of `f` function calls?

Comment: @Constructor you can differentiate between lvalues and rvalues. The second pair of calls will call the second `f`, because they are lvalues. As opposed to the first pair of calls. You can't do this without an alias template or typedef.

Comment: Oh, I see now, you brought this code to show that different overloaded functions are called for rvalue and lvalue arrays. About `f((std::string[]){"Hello", "Folks"});`: why this code compiles both under clang and gcc? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: @Constructor that is a C99 compound literal, not valid C++ syntax. It even has different semantics, because the array's elements will have lifetime throughout the calls scope block (unless the compiler has chosen to implement the C++ extension a different way than C99 describes)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about `-pedantic-errors` flag. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A r-value reference is two things:

- it's a reference, with all that entails
- it's a promise to the compiler that the object referred to is a unnamed (temporary) or can be treated as such

In C++, passing an array by reference allows, notably, to make sure of its length which is already an improvement compared to C's `void func(int a[5])` in which passing an array of length 2 is perfectly acceptable (although good compilers will warn).

The benefit of an r-value reference to an array is less immediate, however:

- a unnamed object cannot be aliased; thus an r-value reference is *necessarily* not aliased, as if `restrict` had been specified
- the caller is warned that elements of the array can be moved

Therefore, there are optimizations possible, even with an array.

Comment: How can unnamed array be obtained?

Comment: `struct A { int array[5]; };` + `A func();` + `call(func().array)` for example. In the latter expression the value returned by `func` is unnamed and therefore `func().array` is unnamed too.

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly a *defect*, it introduces the exciting ability to *move* objects to a target.  This means that the target handle is exchanged for a soon-to-go-out-of-scope source.

Comment: Could you give an example of code which demonstrates your words in applying to rvalue reference to an array, please?